# Value on <apex:input> updating on one field but not on the other

Tags: slds, modal

I have a visualforce page with a modal, in SLDS, with 2 tables in it and some fields from a custom object object. What's happening is that i can update the values on the first row of each table, and they are updated in the controller, but the rest of the rows do not update in the controller. Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

```
<apex:form >
        <div class="slds">


            <div class="slds-modal" aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" id="modal">
                <div class="slds-modal__container" style="max-width:100rem; width:100%; position:relative">
                    <div class="slds-modal__header">
                        <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Page Name</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">

                        <apex:dataTable value="{!productsPrim}" var="product" styleClass="slds-table slds-table--bordered" headerClass="slds-text-title--caps">
                            <apex:column width="20%" >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Nome do Produto</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputText value="{!product.Product2.Name}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column width="10%" >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Número de Beneficiários</apex:facet>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!product.Numero_de_beneficiarios__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column width="10%" >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Valor</apex:facet>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!product.UnitPrice}" />
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column width="10%" >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Dia/Mes</apex:facet>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!product.Dias_Mes__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column width="10%" >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Dia/Ano</apex:facet>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!product.Mes_Ano__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <!----------------------------------------Second Table------------------------------------------------->
                        <apex:column width="40%">
                            <apex:facet name="header" >Produtos Secundários</apex:facet>
                            <apex:dataTable value="{!secondaryProdMap[product.Product2.Id]}" var="prodSec" rendered="{!hasSecondaryProd[product.Id]}">
                                <apex:column width="20%" >
                                    <apex:facet name="header">Nome</apex:facet>
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!prodSec.Product2.Name}" />
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column width="40%" >
                                    <apex:facet name="header">Valor</apex:facet>
                                    <apex:input type="text" value="{!prodSec.UnitPrice}" disabled="{!IF(prodSec.Product2.Valor_Percentual__c,'true', 'false')}"/>
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column width="40%">
                                    <apex:facet name="header">Percentagem</apex:facet>
                                    <apex:input type="text" value="{!prodSec.Percentagem__c}"/>
                                </apex:column>
                            </apex:dataTable>
                        </apex:column>
                            <!-----------------------------------End of second table-------------------------------------------->

                        </apex:dataTable>

                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <apex:commandButton value="Cancelar" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="closeModal()" rerender="modal"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Salvar" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" action="{!gravarRegistos}" rerender="modal"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-backdrop" id="backdrop"></div>
        </div>

    </apex:form>
```

Comment: It sounds like a binding issue. Can you provide some code so we can take look at it?

Comment: added my page to the post :)

Comment: Apparently this is due to a bug with apex:form and the disabled attribute. I managed to workaround this using the boolean that i was using to disable, to render either an input field or an output field. Thank you for your time! :D